# Class '_JsonDocumentSnapshot' has no instance method 'call'. Receiver: Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot' Tried calling: call()

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, runtime-error, stream-builder

I trying to retrieving the data in Firebase with StreamBuilder but it appear this error. Does anyone know how to solve this? Appreciate so much for the help.

**This is my code:**

```
Container(
                child: StreamBuilder(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection('orderInfo')
                  .doc(user.uid + 'order')
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text('No data');
                } else {
                  Map<String, dynamic> doc =
                      snapshot.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
                  return Text(doc['clLady']);
                }
              },
            ))
```

**This is my firebase storage:**
[image]

I want to retrieve the clID but somehow it does not work.

This is the error message.

[image]

Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop the parenthesis at the end of data like this

```dart
               Map<String, dynamic> doc =
                      snapshot.data as Map<String, dynamic>;
```

snapshot.data is an attribute not a method or callable class, thats why you are getting an error.